# Logistic regression and binary data

Tags: r, logistic-regression, binary-data, categorical-data

I am new to R and statistics in general!

I have a binary response variable (yes = 1 and no = 2). I had changed that to yes = 1 and no = 0 (for convenience). I assumed that I would still get the same result in my logistic regression model. However, when I use the original 1/2 response I get a beta that is exactly opposite the 1/0 response variable (e.g. 1.48 vs -1.48).

I am unsure why this is happening and was hoping I can get some help!! Thank you!!